# Appveyor deployment hangs on node gifsicle install

Tags: node.js, build, appveyor, gifsicle

I'm trying to deploy a website using appveyor. I haven't had a problem until now. It seems that the console hangs at the point where it tries to install gifsicle. Here's the console output:

[image]

What could be causing this? From the searching around I've done it seems like it could be one of two issues. Either a lack of memory (highly doubt it) or node can't find a dependency. I'd think that if it couldn't resolve a dependency, it would show some sort of error. Instead, it just hangs like this for an hour and appveyor kills the build. What could be causing this?

EDIT:

---

After visiting the github page of the module implementing gifsicle at https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-gifsicle I see the following:

[image]

Is this what is causing the issue? I would doubt it since it seems the imagemin-gifsicle appveyor build failed quite a while ago (like 11 months ago according to https://ci.appveyor.com/project/ShinnosukeWatanabe/imagemin-gifsicle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [open issue in gifsicle](https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/issues/76) regarding this.

One user solved it by downgrading npm to 5.1.0, but that didn't work for some others.

If you really need this issue solved, I'd say the best route is to contribute your debug info to that thread. Beyond that, you will have to fix the issue yourself, and submit a pull request.

Comment: Any idea why it would build last week, but all of a sudden not this week? We didn't update anything.

Comment: Sorry, I don't. But the install.js script is pretty simple. You should try debugging it. https://github.com/imagemin/gifsicle-bin/blob/master/lib/install.js